# Specifying Source file name using parameter variables in informatica 9?

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have a mapping like

```
 SA-->SQ--->EXPR--->TGT
```

The source will be of the same structure and the tartget also.

There are a bunch of files(with the same structure) which will go through this mapping .

So i want to use a parameter file through which i will give the file names for every run manually.

How to use the param file in session for `Source filename` attribute

Please suggest..

Answer (score 0):

you could use indirect source type, wherein your source file is basically a list of files, and in turn the session reads each of the files one by one.

the parameter file could reference a source file name (the list) as

$InputFile_myName=/a/b/c.list

Answer (score 0):

In line with what Raghav says, indicate the name of a file that will hold a list of input files in the 'Source filename' property box for the SQ in question in the Mapping tab, making the file 'Source filetype' be 'Indirect', specified in the Session Properties.  If you already know ahead of time the names of the input files, you can specify them in that file and deploy that file with the workflow to the location you indicate in the 'Source file directory' property box.  However if you won't know the names of the input files until run-time but know the files' naming standard (e.g: "Input_files_name_ABC_*" where "*" represents variable text, such as a numeric value incremented per input file generated by some other process), then one way to deal with that is to use a Pre-Session Command specifiable in the 'Components' tab of the Session.  Create one that will build a new file at the location and with the name specified for the Indirect input file referenced above by using the Unix shell (or if running on Windows, the cmd shell) to list the files conforming to the naming standard for them and redirect the listing output to that file.

Tricky thing is that there *must* be one or more files listed in that Indirect type of input file.  If that file is empty, the workflow will fail (abend).  An Indirect file type *must* have in it listed at least one file (even if that file is empty) and that file *must* exist.  The workflow fails if the indirect file reader gets no files to read from or if a file listed in it is not present on the server to be read from.  One way to get around this is to make sure an empty file is present at all times that conforms to the naming standard.  This can be assured by creating a "touchfile" before executing the listing command to build the Indirect file type listing file.  In Unix, you'd use the 'touch {path}/{filename}' command ({filename} could be, for example, "Input_files_name_ABC_TOUCHFILE"), or on Windows you'd redirect an empty string to a file likewise named via cmd shell process.  Either way, that will help you avoid an abend.  Cleaning up that file is easy to do: a Post-Session command can be used to delete the empty touchfile.  Likewise, you can do the same for the Indirect type of file if desired.